# How to put delay while opening tab via Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, delay

As `chrome.tabs.create` is asynchronous, it opens link immediately. I have to open a certain links with delay. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)
    {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {method: "sendHTML"}, function(response)
            {

                var val = null;
                if(response.data != null) {
                    lnks = parse_links(response.data);
                    val = setInterval(function(){
                        var total = lnks.length;
                        if (l < lnks.length) {
                            console.log(lnks[l]);
                            chrome.tabs.create({ url: lnks[l] });
                            l++;
                        } else {
                            clearInterval(val);
                        }


                    }, 5000);

                }

            }
        );
    });

});
```

I incremented array indices in loop and as soon as it meets the length, cleared it.